# Can I write aws s3 cp launch commands with EC2

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an AMI on amazon that I launch as needed.  When launching, I want to run some bash commands as available in "3. Configure Instance Details -> Advanced Details -> User Data".  My commands are as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo yum update -y
aws s3 cp s3://mynotebook notebooks/ --recursive
nohup jupyter notebook
```

When I access the instance I launched, the hard drive space is used up as if the files were copied, but I cannot find them!

If I launch an instance, then SSH into the machine and run those commands, the hard drive is the same size as first method (as expected) BUT, the files are available in the notebooks directory which is also the expected outcome.

Where do those files go when using the launch command?  Also, jupyter notebook does NOT start as part of the nohup command.  Am I unable to use these commands at launch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Problem**

User Data runs as root, so those files are owned by root and are being created in the root "/" directory (not your user's home "~"). From AWS documentation:

> Scripts entered as user data are executed as the root user, so do not use the sudo command in the script. Remember that any files you create will be owned by root; if you need non-root users to have file access, you should modify the permissions accordingly in the script.

[AWS User Data Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html)

**What can you do?**

To be able to access your files, you have two options:

1. Use root [**not a good idea for a permanent solution**]

To verify that the cause of your problem is the files' permissions, change to the root user and check for the files in the root directory.

First, ssh to the machine using your regular user (ec2-user, ubuntu, etc...):

```
ssh -i key.pem ec2-user@<your_ec2_public_dns_or_ip>
```

Then, change to the root user:

```
sudo su
```

Your terminal prompt will change to "#" indicating the switch. Switch to the root directory:

```
cd /
```

Now, list all the files and directories with their permissions:

```
ls -al
```

Verify that your files are there. Also, notice the name of the owner "root".

Once you've verified the problem, let's move on to an actual solution; changing the owner and location of the downloaded files.

2. Change both the owner and the location of the files being copied (downloaded).

Assuming you have a normal user called *ec2-user*, modify your script to the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo yum update -y

# Change to the user's home directory
cd /home/ec2-user

# A directory called notebooks will be created in the current directory; ie, /home/ec2-user
aws s3 cp s3://mynotebook notebooks/ --recursive

# Change the owner and group of the notebooks' directory and all its children
chown --recursive ec2-user:ec2-user notebooks

# Run jupyter as the ec2-user
runuser -l ec2-user -c 'nohup jupyter notebook'

# TODO Extract the ec2-user value to a variable
```

**Resources**

[Use chown to set the ownership of all a folder's subfolders and files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/693418/use-chown-to-set-the-ownership-of-all-a-folders-subfolders-and-files)

[Linux Run Command As Another User](https://www.cyberciti.biz/open-source/command-line-hacks/linux-run-command-as-different-user/)

Comment: I was able to verify that files were in there as root.  Thank you so much for the add on piece!  Very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Small tweak to the accepted answer - changing directory and copying files didn't work for me, I modified the script to the below which did work

```
#!/bin/bash
yum update -y
aws s3 cp s3://notebooks /home/ec2-user/notebooks/ --recursive
chown --recursive ec2-user:ec2-user /home/ec2-user/notebooks/
runuser -l ec2-user -c 'nohup jupyter notebook'
```

Answer (score 1):

When copied by the first method, the files are copied and owned by the root user.

Do you have  access to the files? Use "chown" to change the files' ownership if appropriate.

Comment: Thank you!  I switched to root and was able to locate the files!  I'll investigate how to copy for the default user!